# PHP does not load openssl extension

Tags: php, apache, openssl, php-extension, easyphp

I have a problem with my easyphp-dev-server.
I upgraded the PHP Version from 7.1 to 7.3 with this Instruction:

https://www.liberamenteweb.it/en/guides-tutorials-1003/easyphp-upgrade-php-free-without-paying-warehouse-13

After that everything works fine apart from loading the php openssl extension.
In my php.ini I uncomment this and some other lines.
The other Extensions like mysqli are loading.
But not openssl :(

In my Apache error-log I found following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: D:\\ez\\eds-binaries\\php\\php737vc15x86\\ext\\openssl (Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.), D:\\ez\\eds-binaries\\php\\php737vc15x86\\ext\\php_openssl.dll (%1 ist keine zul\xef\xbf\xbdssige Win32-Anwendung.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

The path is the right one and the file exists.
can it be due to the double backslash?
I wonder where it is from because in my php.ini the extension_dir has only single backslash.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Tobles

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.
How can i remove them? In my php.ini the extension_dir-path has just single backslashes

Comment: I would suggest using `/` in the ini file. PHP is clever on Windows and understands the unix directory seperator